# Why can't we pronounce /b/ in 'climb' /mb/, while /p/ in 'limp' /mp/ can be pronounced?

Tags: phonetics

I think it based on voicing and place of articulation. However, i'm not sure if the 'place of articulation' is correct since /m/,/p/,/b/ are all bilabial.

Comment: So maybe it's just about voicing? You've already figured out that it's not about place of articulation. I'm unclear how this is a question about learning English, and not about English phonology in general.

Comment: Oh my bad, this is the first time I've used it. This is a question from my linguistic teacher, and he gives me some cues, but I'm not sure if the 'place of articulation' is correct or not.

Comment: It seems you are confused between "can't pronounce" and "don't pronounce".  Native speakers *can* pronounce /mb/ But we don't pronounce /mb/ except in borrowed words like mbira or iamb; or when it crosses a syllable like "am.ber"

Answer (score 1):

Because the word "climb" is pronounced /klaim/.  There is no particular articulation difficulty with /mb/. There are words like "Amber", "bombastic", and "crumble" that have /mb/.

It is true, however, that /mb/ doesn't come at the end of any words in modern English (except borrowed words from other languages). So in any words that end "mb" the b is silent.  Examples include "bomb", lamb, dumb, crumb and "tomb".  The spelling is not phonetic.

So we are able to pronounce /mb/, but in English we don't pronounce it at the end of words (nor even at the end of syllables).

Comment: It's a whole can of worms, one that opens rather illogically. Bombing, lambing etc it stays silent, but given little excuse it's back again, Bombastic, crumble. Limb - limber, limbic.

Comment: But it's been silent for 700 years, so you have to get used to it.

Comment: thank you, i will consider your reply.

Comment: [What is the origin of the silent 'b' at the end of English words such as lamb, comb, crumb and bomb? by Professor JC Wells](https://www.theguardian.com/notesandqueries/query/0,,-1417,00.html) and an interesting answer on [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/25659/12918).